# React Native - Button onPress not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I don´t understand why my function is not working when I press the button. No error shows. I also tried onPress={this.loginHandler} and theres a message that says

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop onPress is marked as required in Button, but it´s value is undefined.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native';


export default class AuthScreen extends Component {
  loginHandler = () => {
    console.log('P11');
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Button style={styles.btnLogin} title='Iniciá sesión' onPress={this.loginHandler}  style={{flex:1}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Actually, you have to execute the function onPress.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native';


export default class AuthScreen extends Component {

  loginHandler = () => {
     console.log('P11');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Button style={styles.btnLogin} title='Iniciá sesión' onPress={() => this.loginHandler()}  style={{flex:1}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes an error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.loginHandler()'

Comment: I found it See UPDATED answer! Put your function inside of class. :)

Comment: Upvoted, but in the answer an explanation of why it does not work and what should OP do will be better :)

Comment: Putting the function inside the class makes total sense but still doesn't work. I don't understand.

Comment: It should work, can you share your current code by updating your question. Do not replace the old code, just update the question and add the current one, please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either:

```
onPress={() => this.loginHandler()}
```

or:

```
onPress={this.loginHandler}
```

But, the second one is better since it will not be recreated in every render because we are using the reference, not invoking the callback. Here, the problem is you are defining your function outside of your class. So `this.loginHandler` does not point to your function.

It will work like this:

```
const loginHandler = () => {
  console.log("P11");
};

export default class AuthScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          style={styles.btnLogin}
          title="Iniciá sesión"
          onPress={loginHandler}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You are using an external function here, but probably you don't want this since in the future you will want to use some variables or other methods in your class. So, move it into your class and use `this`.

```
export default class AuthScreen extends Component {
  loginHandler = () => {
    console.log("P11");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          style={styles.btnLogin}
          title="Iniciá sesión"
          onPress={this.loginHandler}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  loginHandler = () => {
    console.log("P11");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button title="Iniciá sesión" onClick={this.loginHandler}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I put my function inside the class but still not working

Comment: How do you test your code? I don't know React Native, but `onPress` should be available where do you test this code, right?

Comment: through gennymotion emulator with npm run android. Yes, It should

Comment: What was the problem? I was playing with the Expo right now and it is working :)

Comment: Actually your first answer was correct. I was doing something really stupid. Put console.log to test, but I have no console. Changed it to alert(). Thanks for everything.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want to try this

try to change your function like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native';


export default class AuthScreen extends Component {
  loginHandler () {
    console.log('P11');
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Button style={styles.btnLogin} title='Iniciá sesión' onPress={this.loginHandler}  style={{flex:1}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works!! Actually your first answer was correct. I was doing something really stupid. Put console.log to test, but I have no console. Thanks for everything.

Comment: yeah haha glad to know.. please vote for the answer if it helps you. thanks